# Users Cannot share directly into their facebook pages, only on their profile

Tags: javascript, facebook, share

I have the following way to allow my users to share dynamic content from our site to facebook

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : 'XXXX',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v3.0'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

In the main javascript folder. now for every content i want to be shared i have the following

```
function compartirFB(img,desc,txtTitulo){
        var text = desc;
        var titulo = txtTitulo;
        var url      = window.location.href +'#somehash"; 


         FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.likes',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object: {
                'og:url': url,
                'og:title': 'custom title '+titulo,
                'og:description': text,
                'og:image': img
            }
        })
        },
        function (response) {

        });
    }
```

this works perfectly fine, with a dynamic image. the main problem, is that user, cannot share this content to their own facebook pages, only their main profile as seen in the image below

[image: Unable to share with one of my own facebook pages]

As seen in the image, i'm ubale to share the content in my own facebook pages.

I tried a different way to share the content, but with this option it seems that i am unable to dynamically change the image

```
FB.ui({

                app_id: xxxxx,
                method: 'share',
                href: url,
                image: 'https://ayuntamiento.xalapa.gob.mx'+img,
                title: title,
                description: text,
                caption: 'Quackpower' 


    },
    function (response) {

    });
```

which gives me this window with a default image from a meta tag

[image: Share 2]

Where i can change form where i am sharing, form my profile or any page i manage

Can anyone give me a path to follow?? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> method: 'share_open_graph',
> ```

Open Graph stories are something only users *can* publish, pages never could. OG stories are meant for users to let others now what activities they are currently performing - and pages ain’t people.

> I tried a different way to share the content, but with this option it seems that i am unable to dynamically change the image

The possibility to specify any of those parameters dynamically at share time has been removed a while ago - part of the fight against “fake news”.

The only way to do that now, is if you are posting to a page that has claimed ownership of the content first - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification
But I think even that would mean that you would need to make those posts to a page you are an admin of via API - I don’t think the Share or Feed dialog can handle this dynamically; they would have to switch between the “static” and “dynamic” preview depending on where the user chooses to share, and that is simply not implemented AFAIK.

Other than that, your only option is to create individual URLs on your server that return the desired set of OG meta data when requested. If you need to share the same thing with different preview content, then you can create multiple such URLs, and redirect human visitors that follow those links to the “main” URL afterwards. If you go this route, you have to be aware though that likes and shares for those different URLs would also be counted individually, so you’d effectively be “splitting” those between your different versions of the same thing.